# Can I give a variable to a Jade mixin with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, variables, pug

I'd like to create a variable that contains all the arguments of a mixin then pass the variable to the mixin. Is this possible and if so, why doesn't this work?

```
- var foo = "'arg1','arg2','arg3'"

mixin bar(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  div 
    #{arg1}, #{arg2}, #{arg3}

+bar(foo)
```

Comment: Why is there a `+` in front of `bar(foo)`? Also, `foo` is a string thus one variable. `bar` is expecting 3 variables. That is why it does not work!

Comment: It looks like you need a plus sign in front. From the examples in the documentation http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying does not work because you're using a string as single argument and invoke your bar mixin with a single string. You don't split the string arguments at the ',' character so only your arg1 contains a value.

First let's repair your bar mixin

```
mixin bar(args)
  div
    each arg in args
      | #{arg}
```

The code uses only one argument named 'args'. For this argument some enumerable or array like type is expected. See [jade documentation for more information about iterations](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#iteration). The code block `| #{arg}` writes the arg value as plain text.

How to invoke this mixin? Instead of providing an argument as string you'll need to provide an argument array:

```
mixin bar(['arg1','arg2','arg3'])
```

In case you want to pass a string as argument you'd have to rewrite your mixin bar:

```
mixin barString(argString)
  - args = argString.split(',');

  div
    each arg in args
      | #{arg}
```

Then you could call the barString mixin:

```
mixin barString("arg1,arg2,arg3")
```

Note that I've removed the single quotes for this call.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, you can also do it like this

```
mixin bar(...args)
    each arg in args
        | #{arg}

+bar('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
```